# z/OS/ MVS: How to 'touch' a dynamic set of files

Tags: mvs

In MVS, I'm looking for a UNIX-like touch command to keep thousands of files 'alive' on a seldomly used system.  I have a list of every file name that might exist at any one point in time, but the actual files that exist on catalog can come and go depending on what is running on the system.

HRECALL doesn't work becuase the files are huge, and cannot be allowed to migrate off catalog.

IEBGENER dummy copies don't work because it fails if any of the files are missing.

Is there a 'touch' command that won't fail on missing files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The LISTDSI function in REXX (or CLIST) fits the bill. It will update the last referenced date, which is what HSM uses for migration.

Comment: X = LISTDSI('FILE.NAME' DIRECTORY RECALL SMSINFO)
         SAY 'FUNCTION CODE FROM LISTDSI IS: ' X           
         SAY 'THE DATA SET NAME IS: ' SYSDSNAME             
         SAY 'THE DEVICE UNIT VOLUME RESIDES IS:' SYSUNIT   
         SAY 'THE RECORD FORMAT IS: ' SYSRECFM               
         SAY 'THE DATASET ORG IS: ' SYSDORG                  
         SAY 'THE LOGICAL RECORD LENGTH IS: ' SYSLRECL        
         SAY 'LAST REFERENCE DATE: ' SYSREFDATE

Comment: It accesses each file that I send it, but it does not update the last referenced date. Based on some documentation I have seen online, the behavior you describe seems to have been 'fixed' a couple of years ago.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1OA35217

Comment: I guess they fixed that behavior and documented exceptions back in 1.12 (the last time I wrote stuff that used this behavior was 1.11). Maybe we need to look at USS. Try « touch "//filename" » from USS, or « oshell touch "//filename" » from TSO READY.